# Fade out into one class, fade in in another (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I posted yesterday about cycling through some boxes and everyone was very helpful!

Basically, I have four "boxes" (cor's). Position 0 (cor-last), 1(cor-active), 2(cor-next), 3(cor-third).

When cor-next is click, cor-active fades out and becomes cor-last which has the css of

```
 .cor-last {
top: 800px;
left: 480px;
width: 315px;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 30;
}
```

Then, after x amount of time (setTimeout not put in place yet), it changes back to position three with the css of:

```
.cor-third {
top: 430px;
left: 850px;
width: 168px;
z-index: 10;
opacity: 1;
}
```

But as it stands, ***the image starts changing opacity so you can see it sliding across the screen. Whereas I want it to fade into cor-last (as it does), and fade in after it's already -in- .cor-third's position.***

```
$('.cor-link').click(function(event){
if ($(this).hasClass('cor-active')){
} else {
  $('.cor-link').each(function(index, element){
    ($(element).find('button').removeAttr("data-toggle", "modal"));      
    if ($(element).hasClass('cor-next')){
      $(element).addClass('cor-active').removeClass('cor-next');
      $(element).trigger('click');
    } else if ($(element).hasClass('cor-third')){
      $(element).addClass('cor-next').removeClass('cor-third');
    } else if ($(element).hasClass('cor-active')){
      $(element).addClass('cor-last').removeClass('cor-active');
    } else if ($(element).hasClass('cor-last')){
      $(element).addClass('cor-third').removeClass('cor-last');
    }

  })
    }
```

})
Please bear in mind these are my first few posts here and everyone has been super helpful!

Edit: CSS

```
.cor-active {
  top: 600px;
    left: 500px;
    width: 315px;
    z-index: 30;
 opacity:1;
}

.cor-next {
  top: 500px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 229px;
    z-index: 20;
}

.cor-last {
  top: 800px;
    left: 480px;
    width: 315px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}

.cor-back {
  top: 400px;
  left: 800px;
  width: 90px;
  opacity: 0px;
  }
.cor-third {
    top: 430px;
    left: 850px;
    width: 168px;
    z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="everything">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#corbronze">
    <img src="" />
  </button>
</a>

<a  href="#" onclick="return false;" class="cor-link silver cor-next">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#corsilver">
    <img src="" />
  </button>
</a>
<a  href="#" onclick="return false;"  class="cor-link gold cor-third">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#corgold">

    <img src="" />

  </button>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is all about timing. When you "chain" function, it does not wait. Post your HTML and your 4 CSS classes, so one could work on it.

Comment: Hi there, I thought that was why I would use a setTimeout function. I appreciate any guidance I can get as this is my first big project with jQuery. I've edited the original post with HTML and css. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fork this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EoNYWE) and complete it. You posted 5 CSS classes, but 3 incomplete buttons in the HTML markups. I understand you wish to make a rotation... But make the minimal effort to complete your code so it would be workable. Place some images on the buttons. Then update the code with your try about the use of `setTimeout()`. There is no attempt yet.